# Help with Diamond Square algorithm implementation

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I'm trying to implement the [Diamond-square algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm), but the problem is only part of the bitmap is being filled and I'm not sure what's wrong. I'm doing it recursively:

```
    GLuint CreateDsquare()
    {
        std::vector<GLubyte> pdata(256 * 256 * 4);


        vector2i loc;
        vector2i sz;
        GLubyte val;

        sz.x = 256;
        sz.y = 256;

        val = rand() % 255;

        loc = vector2i(0,0);

         pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 0] = val;
         pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 1] = val;
         pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 2] = val;
         pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 3] = 255;

        loc.x = sz.x - 1;
        loc.y = 0;

        val = rand() % 255;

        pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 0] = val;
        pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 1] = val;
        pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 2] = val;
        pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 3] = 255;

        loc.x = sz.x - 1;
        loc.y = sz.y - 1;

        val = rand() % 255;

        pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 0] = val;
        pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 1] = val;
        pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 2] = val;
        pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 3] = 255;

        loc.x = 0;
        loc.y = sz.y - 1;

        val = rand() % 255;

        pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 0] = val;
        pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 1] = val;
        pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 2] = val;
        pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 3] = 255;

        RescursiveDiamond(pdata,sz,vector2i(0,0));

        return CreateTexture(pdata,256,256);
    }

void RescursiveDiamond(std::vector<GLubyte> &pdata,vector2i psz, vector2i offset)
{
    int val;
    int newnum;
    if(psz.x < 2 && psz.y  < 2)
    {
        return;
    }


    vector2i loc;
    vector2i sz = psz;

    std::vector<int> pvertz(4,0);

    loc = offset;
    pvertz[0] = pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 0];

    loc.x = offset.x + (psz.x - 1);
    loc.y = offset.y;
    pvertz[1] = pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 0];

    loc.x = offset.x + (psz.x - 1);
    loc.y = offset.y + (psz.y - 1);
    pvertz[2] = pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 0];

    loc.x = offset.x;
    loc.y = offset.y + (psz.y - 1);
    pvertz[3] = pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 0];


    val = (pvertz[0] + pvertz[1]) / 2;
    val += 255;
    loc.x = (offset.x + (sz.x - 1)) / 2;
    loc.y = offset.y;

    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 0] = val;
    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 1] = val;
    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 2] = val;
    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 3] = 255;


    val = (pvertz[1] + pvertz[2]) / 2;
    val += 255;
    loc.x = (offset.x + (sz.x)) - 1;
    loc.y = ((offset.y + (sz.y)) / 2) - 1;

    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 0] = val;
    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 1] = val;
    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 2] = val;
    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 3] = 255;


    val = (pvertz[3] + pvertz[2]) / 2;
    val += 255;
    loc.x = ((offset.x + (sz.x)) / 2) - 1;
    loc.y = (offset.y + (sz.y)) - 1 ;

    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 0] = val;
    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 1] = val;
    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 2] = val;
    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 3] = 255;


    val = (pvertz[0] + pvertz[3]) / 2;
    val += 255;
    loc.x =  offset.x;
    loc.y = (offset.y + (sz.y)) - 1 ;

    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 0] = val;
    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 1] = val;
    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 2] = val;
    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 3] = 255;

    //center

    val = (pdata[(offset.y) * 4 * sz.x + ((offset.x + (sz.x - 1)) / 2) * 4 + 0] +
        pdata[(offset.y + (sz.y - 1)) * 4 * sz.x + ((offset.x + (sz.x - 1)) / 2) * 4 + 0]) / 2;

    int ad = (rand() % 12) - 6;
    if(val + ad < 0)
    {
        val = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        val += ad;
    }

    val += 255;

    loc.x =  ((offset.x + (sz.x) ) / 2) - 1;
    loc.y = ((offset.y + (sz.y)) / 2) - 1;

    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 0] = val;
    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 1] = val;
    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 2] = val;
    pdata[loc.y * 4 * sz.x + loc.x * 4 + 3] = 255;



    vector2i newoffset;
    vector2i newparentsz;

    newoffset = offset;
    newparentsz = (psz / 2);

    RescursiveDiamond(pdata,newparentsz,newoffset);

    newoffset.x = offset.x + (newparentsz.x);
    newoffset.y = offset.y;

    RescursiveDiamond(pdata,newparentsz,newoffset);


    newoffset.x = offset.x;
    newoffset.y = offset.y + (newparentsz.y);

    RescursiveDiamond(pdata,newparentsz,newoffset);
    newoffset.x = offset.x + (newparentsz.x);
    newoffset.y = offset.y + (newparentsz.y);

    RescursiveDiamond(pdata,newparentsz,newoffset);



}
```

I suspect that I might be recalling the function with the wrong offset or something.

offset is like the top left and then there is the size, together these nake the square.

what could be wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: one question (I have only scrolled through the code to read the full post): why `255` sometimes and `val` most of the other times?

Comment: @pmg well I was getting zeros so this is mostly for testing, but id atleast expect all the pixels to contain something but most are empty, if I multiply offset by 2 before recursion, half of the screen is exactly filled and the other half only has the first iteration which is why I suspect its in the recursion part.

Comment: what's wrong? you don't explain what you are trying to accomplish and your code is horribly redundant thus hard to read. It uses names like `val` which I believe might be shorthand for `luminosity`, your alpha value of 255 as a bare number already confused one commenter, etc.

Comment: I'm trying to acheive Diamond Square algorithm.

Comment: it should be taking the 4 corners and averaging the 2 on either side to end up filling the 8 pixels surrounding the rectangle, then it computes the center pixel then subdivides into 4 more and repeats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are calculating the offset into your height map for each row (y * pitch) you are using the current size of the square you are calculating instead of the actual pitch which is 256.  The deeper you go into the recursion you are writing into your height map as if it was smaller and smaller until the last step of your recursion is writing into pixel (0, 0).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first, Let's start with cleaning up the violations of [D-R-Y](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), your code should read more along the lines of this:

```
int position( _y, _x, _offset ){
    return _y * _x * 4 + _x * 4 + _offset;
}

void adjust(vector<GLubyte> &pdata, _x, _y){
    GLubyte val = rand() % 255;
    for(int j=0; j < 3; ++j){
        pdata[ position( _y, _x, j ) ] = val;
    }
    pdata[ position( _y, _x, 3 ) ] = 255;
}

GLuint CreateDsquare(){
    vector2i sz;

    sz.x = 256;
    sz.y = 256;

    adjust( pdata, 0, 0 );
    adjust( pdata, sz.x - 1, 0 );
    adjust( pdata, sz.x -1, sz.y - 1 );
    adjust( pdata, 0, sz.y - 1 );

    RescursiveDiamond(pdata,sz,vector2i(0,0));

    return CreateTexture(pdata,256,256);
}
```

Can you format the rest of it down so it's more readable/understandable?  Then I'll update so that I can better answer your question (if someone hasn't beaten me to it or the woman decides I've had enough computer time.)

Comment: Studies show that calling her "the woman" increases the chances that she'll decide you've had enough computer time. In any case, thanks for insisting on DRY.